# a lock that times out in time in a c# web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

My web service has this code

```
lock(typeof MyWebServiceClass)
```

Well i call a 3rd party unchangeable code and it never returns. BOOM!  BAM!

I am locked forever now and my web site crashes.

This never returns only happens once in a great while.

Is it possible to create a lock that times out?  IE lock the code for 5 minutes then release the lock?

Comment: 5 minutes is a LONG time for a lock in the computer world...

Comment: Sounds like it's stuck in a *deadly embrace* (trigger horror music)

Comment: What would be the use? The calling code would still be in a locked section. You can use a timeout for acquiring the lock, and code your way from there.

Comment: +1 don't lock on the type object, lock on a private instance of an object instead.  However it sounds like your main issue is what's inside the lock taking too long, right?

Comment: How many places are you locking on the type of the class?  Is it just the one location?  Trying to figure out if you aren't returning due to a deadlock (what other locks do you request?) or if the problem is really just the call you are locking around?

Comment: yes the problem is inside of the lock itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a timed lock, I would limit your third party request by putting it in a separate thread/task.  Then, kick off the thread (or task if .NET 4.0 and TPL available to you) and join on the response with a timeout.  If the join times out, then cancel the thread (or call the cancel token on the TPL task).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a lock that times out?

Yes, this unpleasant situation is often refereed to as [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Usually it is good practice to lock on a static private object instead of locking on instance fields or the class itself:

```
private static object _syncRoot = new object();
```

and then:

```
lock(_syncRoot) {

}
```

Comment: It seems his question is more referring to his code being performed in the lock takes a very, very long time and sometimes doesn't return at all...

Comment: @James Michael Hare, yes and this greatly increases the chances of getting stuck into a deadlock if you are using instance fields to lock on.

Comment: Very true.  I do agree he shouldn't lock on a type instance, perhaps if we knew more about where/how he was using his locks we'd know more if it's a deadlock or a long-request.  Either way, he should clean up the lock object to be a private instance as you said.

Answer (score 0):

If the 3rd party API has a cancellation mechanism then use that.

```
lock(typeof MyWebServiceClass)
{
  if (ThirdPartyApiThatAcceptsTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
  {
    // The call was successful so proceed.
  }
  else
  {
    // The call timed out so bail out.
    return;
  }
}
```

However, I highly suspect that this API does not have a cancellation mechanism and so that is why you posed this question. If that is the case then this just got exponentially harder.

The naive approach would be to defer the API call to another thread. If the thread does not respond in a timely fashion then you can abort it.

```
lock(typeof MyWebServiceClass)
{
  var thread = new Thread(
    () =>
    {
      ThirdPartyApiThatCouldBlockIndefinitely();
    });
  thread.Start();
  if (thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
  {
    // The call was successful so proceed.
  }
  else
  {
    // The call timed out so bail out.
    thread.Abort();
    return;
  }
}
```

There are many problems with this though. First, there is no guarantee that the thread will accept the abort request. Since 2.0 there are special rules in the CLR that dictate when aborts can be injected into the thread. I believe the CLR will defer the injection while unmanaged code is executing. So if your API is unmanaged then the abort might not work. Also, aborts are voluntary since the thread could catch `ThreadAbortException` and ignore it. Second, aborting is dangerous since the abort can be injected asynchronously. This makes it very difficult to guard against corrupting shared state. That is why the AppDomain is normally terminated after an abort.

The safest way to handle this is to put the API call into a separate process. You would have to use interprocess communication protocols like .NET Remoting, WCF, pipes, etc. to transfer data to/from the call which would be a real pain to maintain. But, it would be the safest since you can safely kill the process without the risk of corrupting the AppDomain of the caller.

I really feel for you because this problem is really hard to solve correctly.